# i want to insert value in column and that value is created by store procedure how can i do this

Tags: sql-server

store procedure that create auto generated password and i want to add this value in password column of table studentlogin

```
create table studentlogin(id int primary key identity(1,1),name varchar(20),username varchar(20),password varchar(20));


create procedure [dbo].[spgenratepassword]
as
begin
    select char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
    cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1))+
    char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
    right(newid(),5) Random_Number
end
```

Comment: This looks like something that would be better implemented as a user-defined function rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: Are you calling this procedure from other SQL code, or from an application?

Answer (score 0):

Use a user-defined function instead (you'll have to pass the NewId() as parameters as non-deterministic functions are not allowed in UDFs):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCreatePassword (@NewId0 as varchar(36), @NewId1 as varchar(36), @NewId2 as varchar(36), @NewId3 as varchar(36))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) AS  
BEGIN 

    RETURN char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(@NewId0))%25)) +
        cast((Abs(Checksum(@NewId1))%10) as varchar(1))+
        char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(@NewId2))%25)) +
        right(@NewId3,5)
END

GO
```

Then insert:

```
INSERT studentlogin (name, username, password)
VALUES ('Test', 'TestUser', dbo.fnCreatePassword(NewId(), NewId(), NewId(), NewId()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest that you should convert this Stored procedure into function so that it can be used directly in select statement

If you insist on using Stored procedure then you should try capturing the results of the exec statement.

```
INSERT INTO <table>
EXEC <sp>
```

is a valid syntax for capturing data.

So you can store results in a temp table and retrieve from it.

See query below

```
create table studentlogin(id int primary key identity(1,1),name varchar(20),username varchar(20),password varchar(20));

go

create procedure [dbo].[spgenratepassword]
as
begin
    select char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
    cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1))+
    char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) +
    right(newid(),5) Random_Number
end
go


create table #password( password varchar(100))

insert into #password(password) 
exec spgenratepassword

select * from #password

insert into studentlogin
select 
name='John' ,
username='johnd',
password= (select password from #password)

select * from studentlogin
drop table #password
```